# Use of 1-a weight in categorical focal loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use focal loss in keras/tensorflow with multiple classes which leads to use *Categorical focal loss* I guess. I have found some implementation [here](https://github.com/mkocabas/focal-loss-keras/blob/master/focal_loss.py) and [there](https://github.com/umbertogriffo/focal-loss-keras/blob/master/losses.py) or [there](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aldi-dimara/keras-focal-loss/master/focal_loss.py).

As far as I get it the parameter `a` in focal loss is mainly used in the *Binary focal loss* case where 2 classes exist and the one get `a` as a weight and the other gets `1-a` as weight. In the case of the Categorical focal loss all implementations I found use only weight `a` in front of each class loss like:

```
    # Calculate weight that consists of  modulating factor and weighting factor
    weight = alpha * y_true * K.pow((1-y_pred), gamma)
    # Calculate focal loss
    loss = weight * cross_entropy
```

or

```
    # Calculate Cross Entropy
    cross_entropy = -y_true * K.log(y_pred)
    # Calculate Focal Loss
    loss = alpha * K.pow(1 - y_pred, gamma) * cross_entropy
```

So, my question is why such a weight factor would make any difference in the training process? Surely, loss is generally used to calculate the amount of weight added to (multiplied by the learning rate that is of course) after each iteration. But this just means that each class gets the same coefficient before it's loss part and so no big deal. This would mean that I could adjust the learning rate and have the same exactly effect? What am I missing here?
What's the exact purpose of parameter `a`?

I also found this implementation [here](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/blob/master/keras_retinanet/losses.py) where they seem to also use `(1-a)` for the negatives examples although they pass the value to `keras.backend.binary_crossentropy` which make it even more complicated I guess.

Any idea of which is the correct implementation?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? If not, could you put a bounty on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL; DR

They are the same. So, just use the simpler one.

Longer version:

(calculation in the toy example have been performed in *numpy* I think the same functionality applies to *tensorflow* also)

After doing some research over the issue I concluded to the following:

- The methods that uses the fixed approach for `a` coefficient indeed apply (a kind of) focal loss in the sense that they inverse the confidence score and power to gamma but it's not exactly the focal loss mentioned in the original paper.
- The second approach seems more accurate to the original approach though BUT they are essentially the *same thing* (at least as it seems in those implementations).

I used a toy example to make some experiments about these losses. For example using 8 samples in 2 foreground classes plus the background we get:

```
gamma = 2
alpha2 = 0.25
preds = np.array(
    [[0.3, 0.2, 0.5], [0.1, 0.4, 0.4], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1], 
     [0.7, 0.2, 0.1], [0.75, 0.15, 0.1], [0.9, 0.05, 0.05],
     [0.72, 0.18, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1]])
gt = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], 
               [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], 
               [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]).astype(float)
```

And the two focal losses would be:

```
focal_log_loss_v1 = -np.sum(alpha2 * gt * np.power((1 - preds), gamma) * np.log(preds), axis=-1)

alpha_factor = np.ones_like(gt) * alpha2
alpha_factor = np.where(gt == 1, alpha_factor, 1 - alpha_factor)
focal_weight2 = np.where(gt == 1, 1 - preds, preds)
focal_weight2 = alpha_factor * np.power(focal_weight2, gamma)
focal_log_loss_v2 = -np.sum(focal_weight2 * gt * np.log(preds), axis=-1)
```

The results show that:

```
focal_log_loss_v1
```

> array([0.14748667, 0.08246617, 0.00223144, 0.00802519, 0.00449503,
>          0.0002634 , 0.00643868, 0.00223144])

```
focal_log_loss_v3
```

> array([0.14748667, 0.08246617, 0.00223144, 0.00802519, 0.00449503,
>          0.0002634 , 0.00643868, 0.00223144])

the two methods are equivalent (!). That was unexpected (at least from my side).
Anyway, the explanation for this is in this command here:

```
gt * np.log(preds)
```

> array([[-1.2039728 , -0.        , -0.        ],
>          [-0.        , -0.91629073, -0.        ],
>          [-0.        , -0.22314355, -0.        ],
>          [-0.35667494, -0.        , -0.        ],
>          [-0.28768207, -0.        , -0.        ],
>          [-0.10536052, -0.        , -0.        ],
>          [-0.32850407, -0.        , -0.        ],
>          [-0.22314355, -0.        , -0.        ]])

which basically eliminates all contribution of all non-ground truth samples (meaning all confidence scores not belonging to the ground truth one). So, even if `focal_weight2` contains non-zero values to non-gt samples they are eliminated afterwards.

```
focal_weight2
```

> array([[0.1225  , 0.03    , 0.1875  ],
>          [0.0075  , 0.09    , 0.12    ],
>          [0.0075  , 0.01    , 0.0075  ],
>          [0.0225  , 0.03    , 0.0075  ],
>          [0.015625, 0.016875, 0.0075  ],
>          [0.0025  , 0.001875, 0.001875],
>          [0.0196  , 0.0243  , 0.0075  ],
>          [0.01    , 0.0075  , 0.0075  ]])

That's why this code produces the same loss:

```
alpha_factor = np.ones_like(gt) * alpha2
alpha_factor = np.where(gt == 1, alpha_factor, 0)
focal_weight2 = np.where(gt == 1, 1 - preds, 0)
focal_weight2 = alpha_factor * np.power(focal_weight2, gamma)
focal_log_loss_v3 = -np.sum(focal_weight2 * gt * np.log(preds), axis=-1)

focal_log_loss_v3
```

> array([0.14748667, 0.08246617, 0.00223144, 0.00802519, 0.00449503,
>          0.0002634 , 0.00643868, 0.00223144])

I am not sure if there should be any differentiation between background and foreground samples though (this is another topic question).

Answer (score 0):

I'm as puzzled as you are as to why they multiply the loss by a constant. The code you supplied has `alpha` as a parameter with the *default value* set to `0.25`, but perhaps when you call the function you're supposed to instead supply a tensor (with the same shape as `y_pred`/`y_true`) with the weights to this parameter? That's the only explanation I can think of.

However, I do think you might be able to simply omit those weights in the code altogether, and instead supply your weights to `tf.fit()`'s `class_weight` parameter, and then that'll do the weighting for you. Could you keep me updated on whether that works?